# Any good NodeJS repos I can reference when building node RESTful API server?

Tags: node.js

I built a few nodeJS webapps earlier this year, but nodeJS development has been so fast that I feel like I'm already out of date. Any good nodeJS repos out there that do a great job building a RESTful api? (in terms of code organization, style, usage of npm modules, etc?)

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give [Express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#http-methods) a try, it's a web framework like Sinatra. There are a lof of example on using it on the github repo: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples

Here's a nice article with code sample: http://fabianosoriani.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/express-api-on-node-js-with-mysql-auth/

Comment: I have used express, but they seem to have quite a few more features/modules for it out now. Thanks so much for the resources!

Comment: There are a lot of modules compatible with Express, since it's the most popular framework for Node.js out there.

Answer (score 0):

I am using express on a webapp and are really satisfied with the request mapping for urls and static content. It also can create basic project structure for a quick start.

https://github.com/visionmedia/express

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is a fast API development: https://github.com/kilianc/node-apiserver

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [node-restify](http://mcavage.github.com/node-restify/)? It's inspired by express and is aimed at creating RESTFull api's :)